# String and integer conversion

Tags: python, django, string, integer, type-conversion

I am writing a project in django.
I am adding rental products with quantity and days into my shopping cart.

Here are my codes.  those codes under "addToCart.py"

```
pid=request.urlparams[0]  #pid is a product id 
cart = request.session.get('cart',{})    #create a cart
cart2[pid]= [days,quantity]     # days, quantity are sent in using forms
```

Those codes under "CheckOut.py". Now I want to calculate totals.

```
product = product.objects.get(id=pid)  # get the product
quantity=int(cart2[(str(pid)][1])     # this does not work. I need some help about how to do int and string coversion
total=product.Price*quantity*int(cart2[(str(pid)][0]) # this does not neither.
```

Comment: What do you mean by it does not work. Getting any exception messages?

Comment: `this does not work.` is not a valid question. What about it doesn't work? What are you expecting to happen? What is actually happening? What is the input? Are you receiving an error? If so, what is it? Please provide the full traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to test it internally with type() function, it might be the case that the stuff you are trying to convert is not convertible to string.